# Weird CSS misplacement on a non-dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a temporary snapshot of my site for the time being: [http://hunpony.hu/today/](http://hunpony.hu/today/?sidebar=open&lang=en)

The problem is, in the right panel, the first div, `div#randomTile.tile` is kind of misplaced.

[image]

I don't know why. Here is some related HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

```
<div id="slideoutWrapper">
    <div id="slideout">
        <div id="slideoutTitle">
            <h1 class="dyn"></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="slideoutInner">
            <div id="randomTile" class="tile" style="">
                <img class="small" src="img/small/vs.svg">
                <h4>Random<br>&nbsp;</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`...` in the CSS mean vendor prefixed attributes, I removed them because it makes the code block too long.

```
#slideoutInner .tile {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:.5em;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:95px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    ...
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    box-shadow:0;
    height:127px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    ...
    filter: contrast(100%);
}
#slideoutInner .tile:hover { box-shadow:0px 0px 15px; ...; filter: contrast(150%) }
#slideoutInner .tile .small {
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    margin:5px auto;
    display:block;
}
#randomTile { color:#777; background-color: #777 }
#slideoutInner .tile h4 {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px auto 2px;
    display:block;
    text-shadow:none;
    color:white;
}
```

Some referenced variables are too long to include here, the main js file is [**here**](http://hunpony.hu/today/.snapshot-130309/js/init.js), where all the code is.

```
$('#randomTile').on('click',function(){
    changeBGImage(rndCharNumber);
}).hover(function(){
    rndCharNumber = randomize(0,backImage.length-1);
    $(this).css({color:colorz[rndCharNumber],backgroundColor:colorz[rndCharNumber]});
    $(this).find('img.small').attr('src','img/small/'+backImage[rndCharNumber]+'.svg');
    $(this).find('h4').html((longNames[rndCharNumber].indexOf(' ') != -1) ? longNames[rndCharNumber].split(' ').join('<br>') : longNames[rndCharNumber]+'<br>&nbsp;');
},function(){
    $(this).css({color:'',backgroundColor:''});
    $(this).find('h4').html(locStr.randomTile[locale]);
    $(this).find('img.small').attr('src','img/small/vs.svg');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    for (i=0;i<backImage.length;i++){
        imgArray.push('<img class="small" src="img/small/'+backImage[i]+'.svg">');
    }

    for (i=0;i<longNames.length;i++){
        h4Array.push('<h4>'+((longNames[i].split(' ').join('<br>').indexOf('<br>') != -1) ? longNames[i].split(' ').join('<br>') : longNames[i]+'<br>&nbsp;')+'</h4>');
    }

    for (i=0;i < imgArray.length;i++){
        htmlArray.push('<div class="tile" style="color:'+colorz[i]+';background-color:'+colorz[i]+';">'+imgArray[i]+h4Array[i]+'</div>');
    }

    $('#slideoutInner').append(htmlArray.join(''));
    ...
});
```

Comment: Have you inspected the css with firebug or a similar tool? You should easily be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes I tried. There appers to be no margin or padding in that particular place. There's some sort of mysterious whitespace I was unable to get rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by white-spaces, they affect inline elements (`.tile` blocks). To fix it add `font-size: 0` to `#slideoutInner` (parent container):

```
#slideoutInner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

and change `margin` of the `#slideoutInner .tile` rule, make it e.g. `4px`. It will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had to chane it to `8px`, by the way. *Still 7 minutes until I can accept an answer*